# Maximum or Minimum energy for transition from $n=2$ to $n=1$ or vice versa?

Tags: energy-conservation, atomic-physics, wavelength, orbitals

I know the maximum wavelength line in the Lyman Series in a **Hydrogen atom** is $n=2$ as transition from $n=2$ (*1st excited state*) to $n=1$ (*ground state*) gives the longest wavelength as per the formula $$\frac{1}{\lambda}=Z^2*R(\frac{1}{n_f^2}-\frac{1}{n_i^2})$$
where $\lambda$ represents wavelength, $Z$ represents atomic number, $n_f$ represents the final energy state and $n_i$ the initial state.

**My Doubt**
We know that energy $E$ is inversely proportional to wavelength $\lambda$. Thus transition from $n=2$ to $n=1$ in the Lyman Series require the least energy.
At the same time when we calculate the total energy of the **ground state** ($n=1$) in a hydrogen atom, we know it is -13.4eV. So lets denote that as $E_1=-13.4eV$. Similarly when we calculate for $E_2$ (i.e the first excited state $n=2$), we get $E_2=-3.4eV$.
Thus **$E_2-E_1=10eV$** and my textbook says this ($n=1$ to $n=2$) is the maximum energy transition when compared to any other transitions.

My professor is man of few words and very much an exam oriented guy and he keeps saying 'Least energy is only in case of the Lyman series. If the question in the exam mentions the word 'Lyman' then write minimum energy'.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Your textbook seems wrong. n=2 to n=1 is the minimum energy, the maximum wavelength, so your professor is right, Lyman series is the minimum energy